# Magento 2 Unit Test With CustomerFactory

Tags: magento2, unit-tests, phpunit

I'm trying to write a test for a function and having the issue:

```
There was 1 error:

1) *******\****\Test\Unit\Api\ShopperDataManagementTest::testGetShopperDataReturnArray
Error: Call to a member function getCollection() on null
```

You can see the method and everything related below, on screenshots. Right now I'm just trying to pass this step. If someone could suggest how can I assert (make sure) this function returns array.

Thank you!

[image: Class for testing]

[image: Test]

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the customerFactory to instantiate and return a customer object:

```
protected function setUp(): void 
{
    $this->objectManager = new ObjectManager($this);
    $customerFactory = $this->createMock(CustomerFactory::class);
    $customerFactory->method('create')->willReturnCallback(function(){
        return $this->objectManager->getObject(Customer::class, []);
    });
    $this->shopperDataManagement = $this->objectManager->getObject(ShopperDataManagement::class, [
         'customerFactory' => $customerFactory
    ]);
}
```

The error is saying that the `$customerFactory` variable returned by the automatically mocked (the test ObjectManager automatically mocks all dependencies) `$this->customerFactory`'s create method is null. You can't call *getCollection()* on null.  When you mock a dependency, you need to implement any methods that are called if you want them to return other than null; otherwise the mock will just return null. This is especially required when a method called on the mock is chained to another method.